# How to convert CSV big number 6.89349E+11 into number with php

Tags: php, csv, numbers

I am importing csv data into my database with php, but big numbers like `6.89349E+11` are saved as shown below.

How to transform them to number or string in a complete way?

[image]

Comment: The number is already complete. It's just a different way of writing it. Are you saving it into a numeric field in your database? What problem is occurring?

Comment: while importing csv you can format your number coloum in csv so it will be imported as a complete number.

Comment: actually I am importing data from csv into php by file upc code is 852733001300 but in csv it change into 8.52733E+11 and save as it in database.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of your issue by editing the question with code and sample data. See also [ask].

Comment: This is a classic that also happens when you import data from Excel. Tell the reader that you read a string, not a number. Remember that computers don't handle infinite large numbers, which is why the number of "shortened" to this notation. Then once in the database, it's stored literally.   You could also convert the number back again, but potentially you lose some digits (example: your number is 689349*1234..* you'd lose the 1234 part.

Comment: @MyICQ `Remember that computers don't handle infinite large numbers, which is why the number of "shortened" to this notation`...it's true computers don't handle infinitely large numbers, but that's not the reason why it's shortened. It the computer couldn't handle the number, it wouldn't be able to output the number in _any_ notation or format. The notation is aimed at _humans_, not computers, to make it more readable and/or save space. I would guess the OP's issue is they're trying to store it in a text field or similar. They need to clarify the problem - speculation is usually unproductive.

Comment: `in csv it change into 8.52733E+11`...what do you mean? Did you generate the CSV from an Excel file, perhaps? Remember to adjust the format settings on the column in Excel, before exporting. And remember also when you save into mysql you should save it into a suitable numeric column type - not varchar or text or anything like that. These are just my guesses about your problem, because you've provided no code or other information to really help us fully understand the problem

Comment: Thank you very much for your time I fond solution simply changing data type of database column from int to BIGINT and increase legnth from 11 to 20

Comment: @MuhammadAmir that's great, but if you found the solution you should post it as an Answer below, not just as a comment. Comments aren't searchable, you don't get points for upvotes on your comments, and so others won't be able to benefit from your solution, and neither will you receive any credit for it. Please add the solution as an Answer - you're allowed to answer your own question. Take the [tour] if you need a reminder about how Stackoverflow works. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

I fond solution simply changing data type of database column from int to BIGINT and increase legnth from 11 to 20